# Can i include a maven sub project into my gradle project?

Tags: maven, gradle

I'd like to include https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-scala into my gradle project as git submodule. This obviously means I cannot edit it. Therefore I want to try getting it into my gradle project as a submodule. However, as you can see, it uses maven (see project/ directory). I am pretty sure gradle has support (the worst case through a plugin) since it also uses maven repositories.

Comment: Why don't you just get the binary from Maven Central (http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmsgpack-scala)?

Comment: Eventually i figured that out, my bad. I do use that now. I think i will leave this question open though, because sometimes what i suggested will be your only solution